# spring data rest: PATCH request with projection param

Tags: projection, spring-data-rest

I am using SDR 2.4.1

When I exec

```
http -v --auth admin:admin --json PATCH http://localhost:8080/api/messages/61?projection=withAccount readTimestamp="2015-12-15T11:32:06.380+0000"
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target bean is not of type of the persistent entity!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:68) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.getPropertyAccessor(BasicPersistentEntity.java:394) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag.getVersionInformation(ETag.java:191) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag.from(ETag.java:76) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.prepareHeaders(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:171) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.prepareHeaders(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:157) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.saveAndReturn(RepositoryEntityController.java:495) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.patchItemResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:442) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

But when I exec:

```
http -v --auth admin:admin --json PATCH http://localhost:8080/api/messages/61?foo=bar readTimestamp="2015-12-15T11:32:06.380+0000"
```

everything is fine.

So it seem to be the projection parameter which causes the exception.

Is this a bug?

THank you

Comment: I have opened a [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1213) for this problem (a while ago).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is a bug - projections are not meant to be used in write request - they are just a way to provide different views on your data. When creating of updating a resource you are tied to your entity structure in spring data rest. The only way I know to customize it is to use Jackson Mixins.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I think the patch request should simply ignore the projection param as it ignores the foo paarm too... Not? ;)